# Volume content of a region $A \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is different for different order of integration$?$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-measure, volume, multiple-integral

I'm interested in computing the volume content of the region $A \in \mathbb{R}^3$ which is enclosed by the following three surfaces :
$$0<x+y+z<1$$
$$0<y+z<1$$
$$0<z<1$$

**Order of integration $x \rightarrow y \rightarrow z :$**

$$\iiint_A\,dx\,dy\,dz=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-z}^{1-z}\int_{-y-z}^{1-y-z}\,dx\,dy\,dz=1$$

**Order of integration $x \rightarrow z \rightarrow y :$**

$$\iiint_A\,dx\,dy\,dz=\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-y}^{1-y}\int_{-y-z}^{1-y-z}\,dx\,dz\,dy=2$$

**Order of integration $z \rightarrow x \rightarrow y :$**

$$\iiint_A\,dx\,dy\,dz=\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-x-y}^{1-x-y}\,dz\,dx\,dy=4$$

What kind of dark magic is this$?$ Am I doing anything wrong in taking the limits of integration$?$

Comment: Only the first integral has the correct limits. Remember that we have to satisfy all the inequalities simultaneously. In the second integral, for $y=-1/2$, $z$ varies from $1/2$ to $3/2$, which obviously is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are errors in the limits.

For example, in the 2nd integral, $y$ goes from $-1$ to $1$ and then $z$ does go from $-y$ to $1-y$ (to satisfy $0\lt y+z\lt 1$) but it also must keep between $0$ and $1$ (because of $0\lt z \lt 1$), i.e. really it will go between $\max(-y, 0)$ and $\min(1-y, 1)$.

The 3rd integral has even more problems. The first one seems correct.

Comment: Thanks. I'm kind of relieved to see the error $($there had to be!$)$. Would you be kind enough to elaborate how to correct the limits in the third integral$?$ I find it complicated.

Comment: @nami_op Unless someone is making you do the 3rd integral, I would just go for the 1st... Note even if the limits are written succinctly (as $\max(-y, 0)$, for example), solving those integrals would require you to distinguish cases. ($y>0$? $y<0$?).

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.